# How to align items centrally when outer div has odd width and height

Tags: css

How to deal with the following issue where outer div is having odd number of width while inner div having even. So, I was working hard on the first set of boxes to align center both horizontally and vertically and came to realization that width was the issue. I thought maybe we cant use `0.5px`. But why its there than. Maybe I am missing something. I dont know please help me in understanding both the cases.

```css
.parent {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.outter {
  height: 45px;
  width: 45px;
  background: red;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

.inner {
  height: 30px;
  width: 30px;
  background: blue;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 2px white solid;
}

.outter2 {
  height: 45px;
  width: 45px;
  background: red;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

.inner2 {
  height: 30px;
  width: 30px;
  background: blue;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 2px white solid;
  margin: auto;
  margin-top: 6.5px;
}

.parent2 {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  margin-top: 40px;
}

.outter3 {
  height: 46px;
  width: 46px;
  background: red;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

.inner3 {
  height: 30px;
  width: 30px;
  background: blue;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 2px white solid;
}

.outter4 {
  height: 46px;
  width: 46px;
  background: red;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

.inner4 {
  height: 30px;
  width: 30px;
  background: blue;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 2px white solid;
  margin: auto;
  margin-top: 7px;
}
```

```html
<h3>Why these are not centered</h3>
<div class="parent">
  <div class="outter">
    <div class="inner"></div>
  </div>

  <div class="outter2">
    <div class="inner2"></div>
  </div>
</div>
<h3>Why these are centered</h3>
<div class="parent2">
  <div class="outter3">
    <div class="inner3"></div>
  </div>

  <div class="outter4">
    <div class="inner4"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: @Dadboz check on chrome.

Comment: Sorry, having a hard time understanding what needs to be centered. It looks like your circles are both centered and spaced out correctly. I'm not seeing a difference between the centered and non-centered..

Comment: @RahulShrivastava this is chrome what do you see at 500% vp : https://imgur.com/gPKgkwa